# Where is Main.axml used?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Android project, I have a file called `Main.axml` and it contains roughly the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/msgText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Where is this file referenced and where does the `TextView` appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main activity's `OnCreate` override, there is...

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```